# Debugging my string tokenizer with gdb

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, gdb

I have a small piece of code that takes in newline-separated words as input and spews out (word,1) as output. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *str1, *str2, *token;
    char *saveptr1;
    char buffer[100];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {
        token = strtok_r(buffer, '\n', &saveptr1);
        printf("(%s,1)\n", token);
    } 
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This code works properly and provides the expected output. However, when I'm stepping through the code using gdb, I get the following error on line 9: the `strtok_r` line.

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   strtok_r () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S:101
>   101    ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S: No such file or directory.

This is puzzling. I'm not even "stepping into" the `strtok_r` line, I'm just "nexting" it, i.e, stepping over. Why does it throw this error during GDB? I am anxious because I have a real, larger program that I can't debug because of this problem. In fact, for most all string functions (`strncmp`, `strncpy`) this problem occurs.

Edit: The compiler did warn about an assignment making pointer from integer without a cast at this line, I should have put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: That seems to have done it.. This is very surprising... I though the \n escape sequence still only counted as a character...

Comment: turn on the -Wall warnings. It will save you.

Comment: '\n' is a character but strtok_r wants a pointer so you pass the const char pointer "\n"

Comment: Thanks terence. That makes sense; however, why does the program compile and run? Yet another one of C's undefined behaviours? :(

Comment: The compiler warns you but yes it is not an error you passed a valid char

Comment: It shouldn't have compiled under C99 or C11 without warnings, either because `strtok_r()` was not declared before it was used (so the compiler doesn't know the types of the arguments), or because the call to `strtok_r()` was erroneous. What command line did you use to compile this, and on which platform? You should make sure your compiler runs with most of its warnings enabled (for example, with GCC, you might use `gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra`; I add `-Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition` because they're a serious problem to me, and I add other options too sometimes).

Comment: Full disclosure: the compiler did warn me about a pointer from integer without a cast, I didn't put 2 and 2 together. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a character literal instead of a string literal to `strtok_r`, the library function `strtok_r` crashes trying to dereference an invalid pointer.

GDB attempts to display the assembly source code for `strtok_r` located in `../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S` (it knows this from the standard C library debug information), but it cannot find the source file at that location.

You should of course correct the code this way:

```
token = strtok_r(buffer, "\n", &saveptr1);
```

It is a good idea to enable as many warnings as possible from the compiler with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and fix the code until the compiler does not detect any suspicious code anymore.

As a matter of fact, you mention using `strncpy`: this functionis **very** error prone.  It does not do what most people think, it is never the right tool.  Read the documentation for it and carefully verify if you use it correctly and if there isn't a better alternative in those places.